# Pause a youtube video from the chrome console after it reaches 3 minutes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, youtube-javascript-api, google-chrome-console

I can pause the video with 
`globalThis.ytPlayerUtilsVideoTagPoolInstance.l[0].pause()`

I can get the current time of the video with `globalThis.ytPlayerUtilsVideoTagPoolInstance.l[0].currentTime`

How do I trigger the pause automatically when the video reaches `currentTime > 180` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way is polling.

```
const player = globalThis.ytPlayerUtilsVideoTagPoolInstance.l[0]
setTimeout(function polling() {
    if (player.currentTime < 180) 
        setTimeout(polling, 1000)
    else
        player.pause()
}, 1000)
```

An alternative way:

```
const player = globalThis.ytPlayerUtilsVideoTagPoolInstance.l[0]
const timer = setInterval(() => { // no need of named function as no 'async recursion' is needed
    if (player.currentTime >= 180) {
        player.pause()
        clearInterval(timer)
    }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Thank you this works like requested.

If I understand this correctly the function polling is calling itself inside of itself every second until it reaches the condition?
Is this called a recursion?
The fact that the the recursion is done every second is called "polling"?

Comment: I would call it async recursion, as it's actually not recusion. What the code does is checking if the condition is met, if not, schedule a check in the next second. Polling, in my opinion, means checking the condition at regular intervals. The code achieves similar functionality as `setInterval`. But if you choose to use `setInterval` to run a piece of code regularly you should remember to cancel it afer the condition met. Added an example with setInterval. The two styles should achieve the same goal.